# How to filter through an array for a user input in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to build a random quote machine where a user can put in a topic word, an algorithm searches for that word within a list of quotes, makes a new list of quotes that contain that word, and then randomly returns a quote out of the filtered list. If there is no word in the list, it would return any random quote. I can't figure out how to make a filtered list in JavaScript. So far I've got:

```
<body>
<p id="quoteDisplay"></p>
</body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="topic" />
<button onclick="wiseQuote()">Quote</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var quotes = [
"You've gotta dance like there's nobody watching, Love like you'll never be hurt, Sing like there's nobody listening, And live like it's heaven on earth. - William W. Purkey",
"You know you're in love when you can't fall asleep because reality is finally better than your dreams. - Elbert Hubbard",
"Being deeply loved by someone gives you strength, while loving someone deeply gives you courage - Lao Tzu",
"In three words I can sum up everything I've learned about life: it goes on. - Robert Frost",
"Everything in moderation, including moderation - Oscar Wilde",
"Life isn't about finding yourself. Life is about creating yourself. - George Bernard Shaw",
"Life is like riding a bicycle. To keep your balance, you must keep moving. - Albert Einstein",
"The truth is rarely pure and never simple. - Oscar Wilde",
"A lie can travel half way around the world while the truth is putting on its shoes.- Mark Twain",
"Perhaps one did not want to be loved so much as to be understood. - George Orwell",
"Facts do not cease to exist because they are ignored. - Aldous Huxley",
"Above all, don't lie to yourself. The man who lies to himself and listens to his own lie comes to a point that he cannot distinguish the truth within him, or around him, and so loses all respect for himself and for others. And having no respect he ceases to love. - Fyodor Dostoevsky",
"A thing is not necessarily true because a man dies for it. - Oscar Wilde",
"The unexamined life is not worth living. - Socrates"
]

if (topic != null){
filteredQuotes = quotes.filter(function(){
return ;
});
}

if (filteredQuotes.length) {
randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredQuotes.length);
filteredQuote = filteredQuotes[randomIndex];
} else {
randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
filteredQuote = quotes[randomIndex];
}

document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = filteredQuote;
}

</script>
```

This is the first project I'm building so I hope this code is not too much of a mess!! Thank you all so much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get value on input and in function of `.filter()` check that items has target text or not. Check it using `.indexOf()`. Then generate random number between `0` and length of filtered array and select one item from array by index.

```
function wiseQuote(){
  // get value of input
  var topic = document.getElementById("topic").value;
  // filter array based of input value
  var filteredQuotes = quotes.filter(function(val) {
    return val.indexOf(topic) > -1;
  });
  // replace filtered array with origin array if it is empty
  filteredQuotes = filteredQuotes.length > 0 ? filteredQuotes : quotes;
  // generate random number
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*(filteredQuotes.length));
  // insert target item into html
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = filteredQuotes[rand];  
}
```

```js
function wiseQuote(){
  var topic = document.getElementById("topic").value;
  var filteredQuotes = quotes.filter(function(val) {
    return val.indexOf(topic) > -1;
  });
  filteredQuotes = filteredQuotes.length > 0 ? filteredQuotes : quotes;
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*(filteredQuotes.length));
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = filteredQuotes[rand];  
}

var quotes = [
  "You've gotta dance like there's nobody watching, Love like you'll never be hurt, Sing like there's nobody listening, And live like it's heaven on earth. - William W. Purkey",
  "You know you're in love when you can't fall asleep because reality is finally better than your dreams. - Elbert Hubbard",
  "Being deeply loved by someone gives you strength, while loving someone deeply gives you courage - Lao Tzu",
  "In three words I can sum up everything I've learned about life: it goes on. - Robert Frost",
  "Everything in moderation, including moderation - Oscar Wilde",
  "Life isn't about finding yourself. Life is about creating yourself. - George Bernard Shaw",
  "Life is like riding a bicycle. To keep your balance, you must keep moving. - Albert Einstein",
  "The truth is rarely pure and never simple. - Oscar Wilde",
  "A lie can travel half way around the world while the truth is putting on its shoes.- Mark Twain",
  "Perhaps one did not want to be loved so much as to be understood. - George Orwell",
  "Facts do not cease to exist because they are ignored. - Aldous Huxley",
  "Above all, don't lie to yourself. The man who lies to himself and listens to his own lie comes to a point that he cannot distinguish the truth within him, or around him, and so loses all respect for himself and for others. And having no respect he ceases to love. - Fyodor Dostoevsky",
  "A thing is not necessarily true because a man dies for it. - Oscar Wilde",
  "The unexamined life is not worth living. - Socrates"
];
```

```html
<p id="quoteDisplay"></p>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="topic" />
  <button type="button" onclick="wiseQuote()">Quote</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working solution; however I want to address a few things with your original code to help you out.

- You come from a Java background, or copied a Java solution from somewhere. JavaScript doesn't have `size()`, it's `length`. Also, you can't use `int` to force a type, as Javascript is a loosely typed language.
- You're `<p>` is inside the `<body>`, but your `<form>` is outside the `<body>`. You'll want to make sure and keep everything you want users to see inside the `<body>` element.
- `Array.prototype.filter()` expects you to return `true` or `false`, nothing else will work.
- Your `wiseQuote` function is literally closed before any of your code starts, tabbing your code will help you spot errors like this.
- I removed the `<form>` element, since you're not actually submitting. This will allow you to not have to try to stop the page from refreshing with `e.preventDefault()`.

```js
function wiseQuote(){
  var topic = document.getElementById("topic").value;
  var randomIndex;
  var filteredQuotes;
  var filteredQuote;
  
  if (topic != null){
    filteredQuotes = quotes.filter(function(quote){
      return quote.includes(topic);
    });
  }
  
  if (filteredQuotes.length) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredQuotes.length);
    filteredQuote = filteredQuotes[randomIndex];
  } else {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    filteredQuote = quotes[randomIndex];
  }
  
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = filteredQuote;
}

var quotes = [
    "You've gotta dance like there's nobody watching, Love like you'll never be hurt, Sing like there's nobody listening, And live like it's heaven on earth. - William W. Purkey",
    "You know you're in love when you can't fall asleep because reality is finally better than your dreams. - Elbert Hubbard",
    "Being deeply loved by someone gives you strength, while loving someone deeply gives you courage - Lao Tzu",
    "In three words I can sum up everything I've learned about life: it goes on. - Robert Frost",
    "Everything in moderation, including moderation - Oscar Wilde",
    "Life isn't about finding yourself. Life is about creating yourself. - George Bernard Shaw",
    "Life is like riding a bicycle. To keep your balance, you must keep moving. - Albert Einstein",
    "The truth is rarely pure and never simple. - Oscar Wilde",
    "A lie can travel half way around the world while the truth is putting on its shoes.- Mark Twain",
    "Perhaps one did not want to be loved so much as to be understood. - George Orwell",
    "Facts do not cease to exist because they are ignored. - Aldous Huxley",
    "Above all, don't lie to yourself. The man who lies to himself and listens to his own lie comes to a point that he cannot distinguish the truth within him, or around him, and so loses all respect for himself and for others. And having no respect he ceases to love. - Fyodor Dostoevsky",
    "A thing is not necessarily true because a man dies for it. - Oscar Wilde",
    "The unexamined life is not worth living. - Socrates"
];
```

```html
<input type="text" id="topic" />
<button onclick="wiseQuote()">Quote</button>
<p id="quoteDisplay"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you both ever so much!! It works and the comments are super helpful :)

Comment: You're welcome. I also updated my answer with some information of why I removed the `<form>` element in my example.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're lovely and the comments are suped helpful! With your code, however, a tiny thing: if you entered a topic that didn't have a corresponding quote (like "jeans"), it'd come up with "undefined". Guess that's because the "else" applied to if "topic = null". I fixed it by mixing your guys codes up and adding `filteredQuotes = filteredQuotes.length > 0 ? filteredQuotes : quotes; randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length); filteredQuote = quotes[randomIndex];` before the "else" part :)

Comment: Updated with a more organized solution to that problem.